# Changing log format in SAP Cloud SDK doesn't work

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I’ve created a new project from scratch using the SAP Cloud SDK archetype. In the project the logback.xml file is configured as this:

[image]

If I run the project I see the following log:

[image]

Now I would like to change the log format and for this reason I slightly modified the logback.xml file as this:

[image]

Unfortunately, running the app again I still see the same log. It seems that the logback.xml file is not taken into account.

[image]

Is there anything missing?

Simmaco

Comment: Could you please add a bit more context to your question: Are these logs obtained from running on SCP Cloud Foundry or Neo? Or on your local machine? Which SDK version are you using?
Also please note that your custom pattern is only very slightly different from the [default one](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/classic/layout/TTLLLayout.html).

Comment: I've deployed the application to CF and these logs are the same if viewed from the console or from the CF Cockpit. I'm using SAP Cloud SDK 3.21.0. I also tried with different patterns, but the result is the same.

Comment: Can you set the "root level" to "debug" or "trace" and check if you see much more entries in the log file? If so, we can conclude that the config file itself is taken into account. Then the remaining question is why the log format config is not applied. Otherwise, the whole config file seems to be ignored.

Comment: I changed the logback.xml file to this:

<configuration debug="false" scan="false">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">         
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>        
    </appender>
    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
but I still cannot see my log formatted accordingly.

Comment: Yes, that intention of that proposal was not to get the log format right, but to figure out if the whole config file is taken into account at all. Thus, do you see now log entries with log level "debug" or "trace" irrespective of the log format? Hint: when you paste code within backticks then it is more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, with a tomee archetype the config file logback.xml is not taken into account on CF. Our assumption is that it can be achieved by "sap_java_buildpack" but currently we are further investigating this issue on how one can change log formats with tomee archetype on CF. In case you want to know how to configure log level in this environment, here is the [documentation](https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/guides/logging-overview) for it.

Regards,
Tanvi

Answer (score 1):

After further investigating we found out that one can achieve this by overriding resources in droplet by placing files in META-INF/sap_java_buildpack/resources/. For e.g. to override logback.xml for your tomee application you need to place it  at path

```
/application/src/main/webapp/META-INF/sap_java_buildpack/resources/tomee7/conf”
```

For detailed explanation here is the SAP Cloud Platform link that you can refer [Link](https://help.sap.com/viewer/65de2977205c403bbc107264b8eccf4b/Cloud/en-US/0a345880fa6f4aa8b7c481ea5677d690.html)

Also this overriding solution on CF is not recommended as it overrides many other log settings on Cloud Foundry. Therefore, unless one has a strong reason to change log format we would recommend not doing this.